# Is it possible to use Access Token for Server-to-Server Integrations in AppExchange uploaded packages? (Salesforce Marketing Cloud)

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, server-to-server

In SFMC documentation it's mentioned that it's not possible for AppExchange Partners to use Server-to-Server Integrations with Client Credentials Grant Type when the package should be uploaded to AppExchange. For the Access Token for Server-to-Server Integrations there is no such note, does this mean it can be used even when uploading the package?

I want to upload an app to AppExchange which needs to establish some kind of API connection from our servers.